# How to check preprocessing parameters of mlmodel (coreml)?

Tags: ios, neural-network, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to get preprocessing info about a coreml model I have.

I'm using CoreML 2.01b.
I tried following this code but It seems outdated as the preprocessing attribute doesn't seem to exist anymore.

```
spec = coremltools.models.utils.load_spec(coreml_model_file)
if spec.WhichOneof('Type') == 'neuralNetworkClassifier':
  nn = spec.neuralNetworkClassifier
if spec.WhichOneof('Type') == 'neuralNetwork':
  nn = spec.neuralNetwork  
if spec.WhichOneof('Type') == 'neuralNetworkRegressor':
  nn = spec.neuralNetworkRegressor

preprocessing = nn.preprocessing[0].scaler   #out of range error
print( 'channel scale: ', preprocessing.channelScale)
print( 'blue bias: ', preprocessing.blueBias)
print( 'green bias: ', preprocessing.greenBias)
print( 'red bias: ', preprocessing.redBias)
```

I tried `nn.ListFields` but Python shell just hangs; I'm guessing too much data?

So not sure what the correct way to get preprocessing info is.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you download [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron/blob/master/README.md) and drop the mlmodel file in there? That should show all the operations in the model.